# Readonly PDF showing NonReadable in Acrobat Reader

Tags: java, itext

I generated a Form PDF and I also made it readonly.
Its working fine with Adobe Reader but When I open it with Acrobat Reader it shows PDF in Non-ReadOnly mode.
I want solution for My Pdf should be readonly for All Readers????

Comment: Not all readers support the *read-only* flag. This is not an iText problem. Maybe you want to *flatten* the form?

Comment: Do you mean the Adobe Reader and Adobe Acrobat? In this case the PDF will be Readonly in both cases. However if you are in "edit" mode in Acrobat of course you can change/edit the fields...

Comment: Thanks @Lonzak i got the solution and I used Adobe Desinger tool to make the fields readonly .